# Dynamically Create LINQ Statements

Tags: .net, linq

I am using a data transfer object (named: SearchSpec) with alot of nullable bools...

```
...
public bool? AL { get; set; }
public bool? TL { get; set; }
...
```

...to filter data from a table using LINQ...

```
var query = (from wv in Source select row); //Init query

if (SearchSpec.AL != null)
{
    query = (from wv in query
             where (wv.AL == SearchSpec.AL)
             select wv);
}

if (SearchSpec.TL != null)
{
    query = (from wv in query
             where (wv.TL == SearchSpec.TL)
             select wv);
}
...
return query.ToList();
```

...which works fine. If a bool is not null, I am using it to filter, otherwise I ignore it.

Now I have to filter some data with more than 50 flags like the two in my example (AL, TL). I could just copy and paste the if-statement like 50 times, but this can't be the right way...

My idea is, to use one big query like

```
var query = (from wv in Source select row); //Init query

query = (from wv in query
         where (SearchSpec.AL!=null && wv.AL==SearchSpec.AL)
         && (SearchSpec.TL!=null && wv.TL==SearchSpec.TL)
         ...
         select wv);
```

This seems better, but it is still copy and paste.

To the point: Is there a way to generate these statements dynamically, for example by using reflection to get all Properties of type `bool?` and then... well, this is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like that;

```
    var query = (from wv in Source select row); //Init query

    query = (from wv in query
                 select wv);

    query = CreateDynamicBoolFilter(SearchSpec, query);

    public static IEnumerable<Source> CreateDynamicBoolFilter(SearchSpec searchSpec, IEnumerable<Source> query)
    {
        //Firstly, bool? properties of searchSpech object are retrieved using reflection
        var booleanProperties = searchSpec.GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool?));

        foreach (var prop in booleanProperties)
        {
            var propValue = (bool?) prop.GetValue(searchSpec, null);
            if (propValue != null) // Determine to prop value is nullable, if it doesn't apply filter
            {
                var propName = prop.Name;
                query = query.Where(x => (bool?) x.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == propName)?.GetValue(x, null) == propValue);
            }
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: I cannot vote you up yet, so I guess a "+1" comment is ok here. Thank you so much!